# llvm: ScalarEvolution: Difference between tripcount and tripmultiple

Tags: llvm

I'm currently working with llvm and I'm concentrating on loops: as I wanted to unroll loops I found out that llvm already provides a function that unrolls loops. That functions expects the following arguments:

- a `count` that determines the unroll count (how many times the loop body will exist after unrolling)
- a `tripcount` which determines how many times the loop will execute (before being unrolled). Or to be exact (taken from the documentation of the `getSmallConstantTripCount` function in the `ScalarEvolution` class):

  > [...] it is the number of times that control may reach ExitingBlock before taking the branch. For loops with multiple exits, it may not be the number times that the loop header executes if the loop exits prematurely via another branch
- a `tripmultiple` which - according to the documentation of the `getSmallConstantTripMultiple` function in the `ScalarEvolution` class - is

  > [...] the largest constant divisor of the trip count of this loop [...]
- some other arguments that do not matter for this question.

The `tripcount` and `tripmultiple` value can be obtained from the `ScalarEvolution` class using the already mentioned functions. My pass currently uses those values but when I started testing the pass on several loops it seems like both values are always equal (when I started using `break`s to create early exits in the CFG llvm could not determine any of those values and always returned "default" values).

My questions are now: what exactly is the difference between those two values? And under which conditions are these values different (some code example would be very usefull)? And could it happen that llvm `ScalarEvolution` pass cannot compute the tripcount but can determine the tripmultiple? And if so some code would be very helpfull as I currently cannot image such a situation.